# Magento 2 Specify target store in .xml files (default.xml, di.xml)

Tags: magento2, multistore, configuration, xml

The title kind of says it all, just to be a bit more specific:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <!-- **** if store == my-special-case-store  -->
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" type="MyPackage\MyModule\Block\Options"/>
    <!-- endif -->

</config>
```

also if I wanted to do the same with "`view/frontend/layout/default.xml`"
how do I accomplish this?

I'm just looking for directions here.

Comment: ` is code  working  for di.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure `di.xml`.  store specifictarget.

**But i am 100% sure that  you cannot make  `default.xml` store specific.**

If you want  **store layout files** and where ***you want to  write store specific layout  code and want to override*** other  existing layout  like `default.xml`.

> **At magento2, layout file name is equal to hanlde name**

Then you need to create custom  extension on this extension we will create**`store specific handler` like** `store_default,store_us` etc,

> where pattern is  **store_`{YourStore_code}`**.

On observer on event`layout_load_before`

- then add your event at observer
- using below code

> $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('store_'.$Storecode);

So, you  create layout files like

> - store_default.xml
> - store_us.xml

```
At app/design/frontend/{Themevendorname}/{Themename}/layout/{Vendorname}_{Modulename}/layout
```

This module should consist of below files:

- `app/code/app/code/{vendorname}/{Modulename}/registration.php`
- `app/code/{vendorname}/{Modulename}/composer.json`
- `app/code/{vendorname}/{Modulename}/etc/module.xml`

Define event at

> `app/code/{vendorname}/{Modulename}/etc/events.xml`

**code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="add_Store_layout" instance="{vendorname}\{Modulename}\Observer\addStoreLayout" />
    </event>

</config>
```

Define observer which  create **store_`{YourStore_code}`** pattern handle

> `app/code/{vendorname}/{Modulename}/Observer/addStoreLayout.php`

**code:**

```
<?php
namespace {vendorname}\{Modulename}\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class addStoreLayout implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $storeManager;
    /**
     * addStoreLayout constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        //['full_action_name' => $this->request->getFullActionName(), 'layout' => $this->layout]
        $layout = $observer->getLayout();
        $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('store_'.$this->storeManager->getStore()->getCode());
    }
}
```

At header.phtml

add this code , and you will see you handler

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($block->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
```

Comment: So I did finally implement this, and worked super! and oh 1 thing please edit your code: "etc/events.xml" to "etc/frontend/events.xml"

Comment: Found an issue, it won't give me the option to insert handle at index, it only adds handle at the end of process queue aka: $layout->getUpdate()->handles private array object. "vendor\magento\framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge.php" lines 73,234

Comment: Removed all items, and re-added them in the order I wanted. Thanks again.